# Split Comma Separated values in a scala dataframe into several lines

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following data:

```
 RecommendationID   TPID    OwnerPersona    RecommendationOwner
   1936946        2494777      AE,AE         DEHARRIS,AACORREL
   2327768        16345463     AE,AE         FLNG,CAZHIWEI
```

I want to modify it to obtain the following result, after splitting the comma-separated string `RecommendationOwner`:

```
 RecommendationID   TPID    OwnerPersona    RecommendationOwner
   1936946        2494777      AE,AE         DEHARRIS
   1936946        2494777      AE,AE         AACORREL
   2327768        16345463     AE,AE         FLNG
   2327768        16345463     AE,AE         CAZHIWEI
```

Note - I just want to split the **RecommendationOwner** column

Answer (score 4):

Just combine `split` to split the string and `explode` to generate one line per item (equivalent to `flatMap` in scala collections or RDDs):

```scala
df.withColumn("RecommendationOwner", explode(split('RecommendationOwner, ",")))
```

You can also get rid of possible spaces by replacing `","` by `"\\s*,\\s*"`.